# Запуск сервера с Python

Tags: python, ubuntu

Сделал `Hello World` на `Python(Flask)`. Запускаю, захожу по `http://localhost:5000` - все отлично. Включаю виртуальную машину, ввожу в браузере `htpp://ip-машины-с-сервером:5000` - Unable to connect.

Пингуется отлично. Если запускаю на Java небольшой Hello World, то все работает. В чем может быть дело ?..

Comment: А вы на каком адресе открываете сервер на прослушку? Вот так запускаете: `flask run --host=0.0.0.0` ?

Comment: Не, просто `flask/bin/python run`.  Попробовал по вашему - результат не изменился.

Comment: Может из-за опечатки в `htpp` ? Или это только здесь она?

Comment: приведите *точные команды* (copy-paste), которые вы используете (с минимальным примером кода).

Comment: Использую пример проекта вот от сюда https://habrahabr.ru/post/193242/. Запускаю командой `flask/bin/python run.py`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Путь диагностики сложен и тернист. Для начала надо узнать как организована сеть на виртуальной машине - бридж там, либо, например, NAT. Если НАТ - надо прокинуть порты, если бридж то переходить к диагностике дальше.

Сбросить правила для iptables `iptables -F` и `iptables -X`

Посмотреть слушает ли костыль нужный порт и нужный адрес: `ss -tunap|grep 5000`

Снять дамп на виртуальной машине: `tcpdump -ni any port 5000` из которого будет видно, доходят ли запросы и что с ними происходит.

Дебажить костыль с помощью strace (Скорее всего его надо будет установить): `strace flask/bin/python run.py` в котором будет отчётливо видно, что происходит в системе при вызове костыля, разумеется, если вызов до него доходит.

Дальше по ситуации.

Answer (score 2):

`netstat -tulpn` в консоли и смотреть кто слушает порт 5000.
У виртуальной машины NAT или Bridge настроен в свойствах сети? Надо Bridge настроить.